# How to dynamically change text size inside a card?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a table filled with **changed** number of rows and cols.

I would like to change the size of the text inside each card to be the maximum possible size so the words will still be able to read comfortably.

The words inside the cards change each time.

Thank you.

```
  class GameCardButton extends StatelessWidget {   final String word;  final Color cardColor;

  GameCardButton({@required this.word, this.cardColor});

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
        //TODO: implement onPressed
        onPressed: () {},
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal),
        ),
        child: Text(
          word,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );   } }
```

[image: good example]
[image: bad example]

Comment: The [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) has some options that can do what I think you want.

Comment: Yea, I tried it, but I want all the words to be in the same size.

Comment: Did you use the [`group`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text#group) option?

Comment: if space is less and text is longer, then how you can have same size?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `Text` widget like this:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Text(
          word,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Thank you, now each card is filled with different text size, is there any way to set one size for all texts?